# fstream c ++ functions return full line fstream

Tags: c++

C ++ language for the creation of a personal web, here I use `C++` as cgi to output to a web server `XAMP`, with load `fstream` to separate manuscript with `c ++ html`, making `htmlstream` function as pieces that are not too complicated in notepad while coding `c ++`, the problem is when a function `htmlstream` made, only one line of text, it can not display all the text

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string htmlstream(const char* _filename){
    string htmltext;
    fstream open_html (_filename);
    if(open_html.is_open()){
            while(getline(open_html,htmltext)){
                    return htmltext;
            }
    }else{
    cout<<"File: NO Reading"<<endl;
    }
}
int main(){
    string importhtml = htmlstream("body.html");
    cout<<importhtml;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why one line of text is only display is because the function getline reads until it reaches the end of the current line. That is, every time a line is read, the value of the string variable is changed. 
If storing the value of each line is what you want, then you will have to append every line as you read. There are multiple solutions, I decided to go with something simple.

See if this helps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

/// Simplify calls to the standard library
using namespace std;

string htmlStream( const char *fileName )
{
    string   text;      /// Content of current file
    ifstream inFile;    /// Input file stream

    inFile.open( fileName );  /// Open file to read

    if ( inFile.is_open() ) {
        /// File successfully open, so process it
        string line;  /// String being read

        /// Read file, line by line
        while ( getline( inFile, line ) ) {
            text += line;
        }
    }
    else {
        /// Could not open file, so report error to the stderr
        cerr << "Cannot open \"" << fileName << "\"" << endl;
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    return text;
}

int main( int argc, const char * argv[] ) {

    string str = htmlStream( "darkness.txt" );

    cout << str << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```